# What is the difference between memory leak, accessing freed memory and double free?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between those three kinds of problems associated with memory models.

If I want to simulate a `memory leak` scenario, I can create a pointer without calling corresponding delete method.

```
int main() {
    // OK
    int * p = new int;
    delete p; 

    // Memory leak
    int * q = new int;
    // no delete
}
```

If I want to simulate a `double free` scenario, I can free a pointer twice and this part memory will be assigned twice later.

```
a = malloc(10);     // 0xa04010
b = malloc(10);     // 0xa04030
c = malloc(10);     // 0xa04050

free(a);
free(b);  // To bypass "double free or corruption (fasttop)" check
free(a);  // Double Free !!

d = malloc(10);     // 0xa04010
e = malloc(10);     // 0xa04030
f = malloc(10);     // 0xa04010   - Same as 'd' !
```

However, I don't know what is `accessing freed memory`. Can anybody give me an example of `accessing freed memory`?

Answer (score 5):

1. Memory leaks are bad.
2. Double frees are worse.
3. Accessing freed memory is *worser*.

#### Memory leaks

This is not an error *per se*. A leaking program is stil valid. It may not be a problem. But this is still bad; with time, your program will reserve memory from the host and never release it. If the host's memory is full before the program completion, you run into troubles.

#### Double frees

Per the standard, this is undefined behaviour. In practice, this is almost always a call to `std::abort()` by the C++ runtime.

#### Accessing freed memory

Also undefined behaviour. But in some case, nothing bad will happen. You'll test your program, put it in production. And some day, for no apparent reason, it will *break*. And it will break hard: randomly. The best time to rework your résumé.

And here is how to access freed memory:

```
// dont do this at home
int* n = new int{};
delete n;
std::cout << *n << "\n"; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR. DONT.
```

Comment: "break" suggests a crash - I feel it should be pointed out that the 'break' might be just reading the wrong data.  Which doesn't sound bad until you've given someone permission to delete files for one login session only and all your logging says they can't etc etc (hence the new resume requirement)

Comment: @UKMonkey have you heard of nasal demons?

Comment: is that why I keep sneezing?  I knew I was being cursed by something  (actually, no, I hadn't - but glad I googled it) - a nice addition to the answer though :)

Comment: Double frees: ... unless the memory has already been reused! Just think about what happens when you `delete myFoo` when the memory has already been reused for a `new Bar()`... I'd see the double free just as a special form of accessing freed memory.

Comment: @cmaster Imagine the following scenario: `a=new int; delete a; b=new int /*suppose reuse => a==b*/; delete a; /* ... */ delete b /* => abort()*/;`: You get a freed memory access, but also a merciful abort.

Comment: I know that there are cases where you just get shot. **But that's only if you are lucky**. You may also be formatting your harddrive unknowingly... Just insert another use of `*b` between the `delete a;` and the `delete b;`, the result will be totally undefined.

Comment: Imho, the only thing special about a double-free is, that it is a **detectable** form of use-after-free. It's not any less dangerous, though.

Comment: @cmaster you'd say both should be _worser_ :D? Anyway I agree, both are really bad. I just wanted to order them to get some fun. (edit: wrote that before reading your last comment; we agree then ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your examples of a memory leak (allocating memory but freeing it) and double-free (passing a pointer to allocated memory to `free` / `delete` more than once) are correct.

Performing a double-free does not however mean that a section of memory will be returned more than once by `malloc` as your example indicates.  What it does do is invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning the behavior of your program cannot be predicted going forward.

Accessing free'ed memory means freeing a pointer and then subsequently trying to use it:

```
int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));     // allocate memory
free(a);                               // free memory
print("a[0]=%d\n", a[0]);              // illegal: use after free
```

Comment: Can this be considered as one of example? New an array which length is 3, delete it and try to access its component. `c = new int[3];  delete c;  res = c[2];`

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit Yes, it's the same thing.

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit yes your example counts valide.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about making a memory leak and a double-free. Accessing freed memory happens when you dereference a pointer that has been freed:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 123;
free(ptr);
int invalid = *ptr; // Accessing freed memory
```

Problems like this are notoriously hard to detect, because the program continues to work as expected for some time. If you expect to reuse the pointer variable at some later time, it is a good idea to assign it `NULL` immediately after calling `free`. This way a subsequent dereference would fail fast.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between those three kinds of problems associated with memory models.

- memory leak - you dynamically allocate memory and never release it.
- double free - you dynamically allocate memory and release it multiple times
- accessing after free - you dynamically allocate memory then release and access that memory after release.

Comment: I believe it would be more correct to say that memory leak is when memory is unreleased and unreferenced (therefore not releasable).

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon no it would not. For example cross reference in smart pointers. Memory is referenced, but still memory leak.